# How to Update and Delete MySQL Table in PHP using this kind of method?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Using laracasts 'The PHP Practitioner' course I learn that I can insert into table using following format:

```
public function insert($table, $parameters)
{
    $sql = sprintf(
        'insert into %s (%s) values (%s)',
        $table,
        implode(', ', array_keys($parameters)),
        ':' . implode(', :', array_keys($parameters))
    );

    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $statement->execute($parameters);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //
    }
}
```

How I update and delete data using this method just passing table name and array as arguments in PHP?

Comment: The Update and Delete methods will need the `WHERE` clause most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for:

```
public function delete($table, $where = [])
{
    $_where = array_reduce(array_keys($where), function($prev,$key){
        return $prev . ' AND ' . $key . '=:' . $key;
    },'1=1');
    $sql = sprintf(
        'delete from %s where %s',
        $table,
        $_where
    );

    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $statement->execute($where);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //
    }
}


public function update($table, $values, $where=[]){
    $_where = array_reduce(array_keys($where), function($prev, $key){
        return sprintf("%s AND %s=:%s", $prev, $key, $key);
    },'1=1');
    $_set = array_reduce(array_keys($values), function($prev, $key){
        return sprintf("%s,%s=:%s", $prev, $key, $key);
    }, '');
    $sql = sprintf(
        'update %s set %s where %s',
        $table,
        $_set,
        $_where
    );
    try {
        $statement = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $statement->execute($where);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //
    }
}
```